# Observe change of object proprty in nested array in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, ember.js

We have this data structure

```
[[{foo:"12", bar:"34"}, {foo:"33", bar:"55"}], [{foo:"45", bar:"67"}]]
```

How is it possible to make a computed property to observe a change on `foo` or `bar`?

Comment: It depends on what you need to cover. What about `array[0][0] = {foo:"89", bar:"01"}` would that constitute as a change?

Comment: The objects in the arrays dont get overwritten, only their properties change or objects are added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you use `.@each.someProperty` in a computed property to watch specific object properties in an array but in the case of nested arrays (or nested objects), you can't do `.@each.@each.someProperty` because `.@each` only works one level deep.

You need to use intermediary computed properties to raise the inner objects up one (or more) levels and have another computed property watch these in turn. There may be other ways to wire things up, but this is a pretty straightforward way to do it.

Here's a [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/03bdfc7c1d6f89672a2ac4598eb77e1e?openFiles=components.my-component.js%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs) that demonstrates it. If you open the console you can see the individual computed properties recording a change occurring.

You can also use an [alias](http://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.13/functions/@ember%2Fobject%2Fcomputed/alias) to pull the inner arrays / objects up a level or two.